# Accented characters in Matplotlib

Tags: python, unicode, matplotlib

Is there a way to get Matplotlib to render accented chars (é,ã,â,etc)?

For instance, I'm trying to use accented characters on `set_yticklabels()` and Matplotlib renders squares instead, and when I use `unicode()` it renders the wrong characters.

Is there a way to make this work?

It turns out you can use u"éã", but first you have to set the file encoding:

```
# Using the magic encoding
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

After that Matplotlib correctly renders

```
u"é"
```

I also learned that you can use

```
import matplotlib.font_manager as fm
fp1=fm.FontProperties(fname="/path/to/somefont.ttf")
ax.title("é",fontproperties=fp1)
```

in case you need to render a characters that Matplotlib does not have.

Comment: Good question. Unicode has a rich repertoire of mathematical symbols, and I would hope that Unicode would work when used.

Comment: Is there a way to mimic this behaviour using the interactive mode? (For example, I'm using IPython.) The trick with using font manager didn't work for me.

Comment: Nevermind, this is an issue with [IPython itself](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/labels/unicode#issue/25).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Prefix the strings with `u` to tell Python that they are Unicode strings:

```
ax.set_yticklabels([u'é', u'ã', u'â'])
```

Comment: Thanks for your input ptomato but it renders the wrong characters when i use u"é" or unicode('é','latin-1'), do these work for you?

Comment: Yes, those work for me. As you say in your update, it was your file encoding that was causing the problem.

Comment: What happens with those certain characters? I am guessing you did not include `coding: utf8` in a comment at the top of the file.

Comment: @DrunkenMaster see the answer for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960463/non-ascii-characters-in-matplotlib

Answer (score 8):

Sure. You can use TeX:

```
from matplotlib import rcParams
rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
ax = ... # Axes object
ax.set_yticklabels(['$\'{e}$', '$\tilde{a}$', '$\hat{a}$'])
```

Comment: Using tex works, but since the text to be rendered is in a database (unicode) i will have to "convert" it every time, or there is a easier solution here?

Comment: Oh, okay. Yeah, then this solution might be annoying. Use the other solution.

Answer (score 5):

I also had this problem specifically when I was trying to use the annotate function. Here was my error message:

```
ValueError: matplotlib display text must have all code points < 128 or use Unicode strings
```

And here's what I used to resolve this:

```
"accented string i.e. sāo paulo".decode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 1):

from matplotlib import rc

```
rcParams['text.latex.unicode']=True
```