# Non-ASCII characters in Matplotlib

Tags: python, unicode, matplotlib, ascii

I have a problem displaying non-[ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) characters in Matplotlib, these characters are rendered as small boxes instead of a proper font, it looks like (I filled these boxes with red paint to hightlight them):

[image: Here is the image showing the problem]

How do I fix it?

A related question is *[Accented characters in Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406700)*.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

This problem may actually have a couple of different causes:

**The default font does not include these glyphs**

You may change the default font using the following (before any plotting is done!)

```
matplotlib.rc('font', family='Arial')
```

In some versions of matplotlib you'll have to set the family:

```
matplotlib.rc('font', **{'sans-serif' : 'Arial',
                         'family' : 'sans-serif'})
```

(Note that because `sans-serif` contains a hyphen inside the `**{}` syntax, it is actually necessary.)

The first command changes the `sans-serif` font family to contain only one font (in my case it was [Arial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arial)), the second sets the default font family to `sans-serif`.

Other options are included [in the documentation](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/customizing.html).

**You have improperly created/passed string objects into Matplotlib**

Even if the font contains proper glyphs, if you forgot to use `u` to create [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) constants, Matplotlib will have this behaviour:

```
plt.xlabel("Średnia odległość między stacjami wsparcia a modelowaną [km]")
```

So you need to add `u`:

```
plt.xlabel(u"Średnia odległość między stacjami wsparcia a modelowaną [km]")
```

Another cause is that you forgot to put a [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) magic comment on top of the file (I read that this [might be the source of the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406700/accented-characters-in-matplotlib)):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Comment: According to the [docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text.set_family), you can directly pass a font name rather than a family. This works for me: `matplotlib.rc('font', family='DejaVu Sans')`

Comment: This is definetely better syntax! I'll leave the old one in case it was actually neccessary for some kind of ancient matplotlib version.

Comment: In case you want to avoid adding `u`, use this: from __future__ import unicode_literals