# write an upright mu in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, spyder

I'm trying to put an upright mu in my axes labels, but matplotlib just shows a square box.

Example code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1,2],[3,4])
plt.xlabel(u"A distance (μm)")
plt.show()
```

The weird thing is: when I run this directly in the interactive python interpreter that spyder has open when it starts, the μ shows up fine. When I run it from a .py file in a dedicated interpreter however, it shows up as '?' or as a square.

What does spyder's python interpreter do that I'm not? What do I need to import to make it work regardless of where the script is run from?

note: I know I could also do something like "A distance ($\mu$m)$, but that creates an italic mu which is typographically incorrect for units...

Comment: Do the terminal and editor you're using support utf-8?  Does your locale enable utf8?

Comment: You can avoid italic characters by writing '$\mathrm{...}$'. Sadly for you, this has no effect on the \mu. You might want to change the LaTeX Preamble to include a package like upgreek to work around that?

Comment: Perhaps [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960463/non-ascii-characters-in-matplotlib) (and answer) help?

Comment: @BrianCain: I don't know... The editor and interpreter do I suppose, since the character shows up ok when I type (ctrl-v) it. How can I check whether or not my locale enables is?

Comment: @Faultier: I know, I've done that in the past, but it's complicated and slower. A unicode μ would just make everything much easier.

Comment: @Evert: No I don't think so. I did everything it says (unless I missed something:)), u in front of the string, magic comment, the lot

Comment: @jkokorian, which OS are you using?  `mac`/`linux`/`*nix`?  If so, do `locale` or `env|grep -i lang` at a command prompt.

Comment: @BrianCain windows...

Comment: Sorry to waste your time guys. It turns out I didn't properly switch the font to Arial, I'll answer my own question.

Comment: @jkokorian, glad you figured it out.  FYI the windows `cmd.exe` terminal likely does not support utf8 by default.  [try changing the code page](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1259468/489590).

Comment: Thank you all very much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The suggestion from [Non-ASCII characters in Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960463/non-ascii-characters-in-matplotlib) to add this line did the trick:

```
plt.rc('font', **{'sans-serif' : 'Arial', 'family' : 'sans-serif'})
```

I thought I already had that covered because I had added the following line to my rcParams dictionary:

```
plt.rcParams.update({'font.sans-serif': 'Arial', 'font.family': 'sans-serif'})
```

Not the same thing aparently.

Comment: setting `text.usetex=True` will let you use `\textmu` as well.