# How to show ℃ in the legend of matplotlib, python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

Below are some pieces of code, but I really do not know how to let ℃ shows as it should be.
I think matplotlib is powerful enough to do tihs kind of job. Any experts can help me out of this dilemma？

```
if i==12:
    plot(strain,stress,'1-',label="$1200℃$")

xlabel(r"strain/$\epsilon$",fontsize=18)
ylabel("stress/MPa",fontsize=18)

legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.01, 1.0,0.8,0.0), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.0)

show()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Non-ASCII characters in Matplotlib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960463/non-ascii-characters-in-matplotlib)

Comment: MathTextWarning: Font 'rm' does not have a glyph for 'b'\\u2103''[U2103]. 
This is warning from python, I have read the links you gave to me, however, still have no idea how to fix it. I have tried using" # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-", but it does not help.

Comment: Font 'rm'??  Did you set it via: `matplotlib.rc('font', family='Arial')` ?

Comment: No, I did not do that. Actually this warning comes from ℃, because after I deleted the ℃, there is no warning. However without ℃, the figure will be less meaningful, since nobody knows the meaning of the legend.

Comment: Well, that was the most relevant part of the link I posted.

Comment: You should try *all* the solutions discussed in the linked answer. You are trying to display a unicode character (℃), which the default font does not include. You may also need to prefix your string with `u''`, if you are using Python 2.

Comment: Thank you for your patient guide and reply,   Marius. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution is completely separate to the font/unicode issues discussed in the duplicate, but you can use Latex-style commands to get this working:

```
plt.plot(1, 3, '1-', label=u"$1200^{\circ}C$")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Good lord, Thank you for your solution. You are really good at matplotlib. My level is too low, still need to learn more...Latex-style pretty cool!!

Comment: This solution is not really so much about having deep matplotlib knowledge, it's more about being familiar with Latex's math formatting commands, which matplotlib happens to (partly) support.

Comment: Nice - even simpler alternative.

Comment: Yeah, I knew matplotlib support Latex formatting. Still, I do not dive so deep into it so far as you do. It really helps~