# unicode text when using savefig() in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I am new to matplotlib and trying to plot a 2D/3D chart with non-ASCII texts in it, I am able to use `show()` to plot on screen:

```
plt.text(X, Y, str(text[i].decode('utf-8')) )
plt.show()
```

However when I try to save the figure to a file with
`savefig()`, all texts become little squares `[]`

I am sure it is a font related problem but I can't see to figure out how to fix this.

I am on a Mac OSX 10.10.5, if that matters.

Comment: Probably a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960463/non-ascii-characters-in-matplotlib

Comment: Thanks, I googled that question but I try the suggested fonts without luck.

Comment: Yes, it depends very much on your unicode characters and the character map of the font. E.g. Arial won't have any glyphs for Chinese characters.

Answer (score 1):

finally solved it by using:

```
fontpath = '/Library/Fonts/华文细黑.ttf'
properties = font_manager.FontProperties(fname=fontpath)
matplotlib.rcParams['font.family'] = properties.get_name()
```