# How to create a Bar Chart with Python Pandas with Greek Labels

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

i am trying to make a bar chart using pandas and matplotlib. The data is depicted in the dataframe (champs_by_number_of_matches) bellow and it is Greek.

[image]

```
by typing: champs_by_number_of_matches.plot(kind = 'bar')
```

i get the graph bellow. How can i get the x-axis labels to show Greek?
This is a frequent problem i have encountered and i dont want to convert the labels to "Greeklish".

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: I think it's a font issue that can be solved by typing `matplotlib.rc('font', family='Arial')` (from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960463/non-ascii-characters-in-matplotlib)

Comment: @ayhan IT WORKS!. but... just in case; are there any other solutions? such as to change axis enconding. i would like a plan B.

Comment: It's not an encoding issue but a font one. The default matplotlib font does not include those characters so you need to change the characters or change the font.

Comment: The new default font in mpl 2.0 will have more code points (and I believe including the greek ones).