# Why does Matplotlib's PdfPages print tabs as boxes (font encoding)?

Tags: python, pdf, matplotlib, character-encoding, pdf-generation

when I run a modified version of [Matplotlib's multi page example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/multipage_pdf.html) with a tab added to the title, I get the following output:

[image]

This is my working example. The comments above the code are suggestions I found [here](http://phyletica.org/matplotlib-fonts/) and in [Non-ASCII characters in Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960463/non-ascii-characters-in-matplotlib), but no success so far.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
from pylab import *

#matplotlib.rc('font', family='DejaVu Sans')

#matplotlib.rc('font', **{'sans-serif' : 'Arial',
#                           'family' : 'sans-serif'})

#matplotlib.rcParams['pdf.fonttype'] = 42
#matplotlib.rcParams['ps.fonttype'] = 42

pdf = PdfPages('multipage_pdf.pdf')

figure(figsize=(3,3))
plot(range(7), [3,1,4,1,5,9,2], 'r-o')
title('Page\tOne')
savefig(pdf, format='pdf') # note the format='pdf' argument!
close()

pdf.close()
```

Any ideas how this could be solved?

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to add

```
matplotlib.rcParams['ps.useafm'] = True
matplotlib.rcParams['pdf.use14corefonts'] = True
matplotlib.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
```

as mentioned [here](https://brainlogging.wordpress.com/2011/11/16/type-1-vs-3-fonts/) and [here](http://nerdjusttyped.blogspot.de/2010/07/type-1-fonts-and-matplotlib-figures.html).

I couldn't find out which line does the magic, not all seemed to be needed in my case, but I just added all. If there is a problem with tex complaining about not being able to encode something, you might be able to comment the `['text.usetex']` with it still working.

From the matplotlib doc:

> Add "pdf.use14corefonts: True" in your configuration file to use only
>   the 14 PDF core fonts. These fonts do not need to be embedded; every
>   PDF viewing application is required to have them. This results in very
>   light PDF files you can use directly in LaTeX or ConTeXt documents
>   generated with pdfTeX, without any conversion.
>
> These fonts are: Helvetica, Helvetica-Bold, Helvetica-Oblique,
>   Helvetica-BoldOblique, Courier, Courier-Bold, Courier-Oblique,
>   Courier-BoldOblique, Times-Roman, Times-Bold, Times-Italic,
>   Times-BoldItalic, Symbol, ZapfDingbats.