# How to print 'ந ே' as 'நே' in matplotlib plot function? Rendering Problem

Tags: python, matplotlib, tamil

Unable to print tamil words correctly in matplotlib plot function.

Here is my code:

```
xx=['என்று', 'தான்', 'ஒரு', 'இந்த']
yy=[1,3,2,5]

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rc('font', family='Vijaya')
plt.plot(xx,yy, 'go-')
plt.xlabel("சொற்கள்")
plt.ylabel("எண்ணிக்கை")
```

Comment: You need to use a font that support those characters.

Comment: Related – [Non-ASCII Characters in Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960463/non-ascii-characters-in-matplotlib)

Comment: @TrebledJ I tried all the methods listed in the link. But could not be able to resolve the problem.

Comment: @RaRaa Please show code (a [mcve]) that reproduces your problem.

Comment: @TrebledJ 
`xx=['என்று', 'தான்', 'ஒரு', 'இந்த']`
`yy=[1,3,2,5]`
`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`
`plt.rc('font', family='Vijaya')`
`plt.plot(xx,yy, 'go-')`
`plt.xlabel("சொற்கள்")`

`plt.ylabel("எண்ணிக்கை")`