# Conversion of unicode minus sign ( from matplotlib ticklabels )

Tags: python, string, unicode, python-2.7, matplotlib

I'm having a problem with the Text object that matplotlib use to represent the ticklabels.

For testing reason I need to check the value of the ticks labels that are created in a plot. If the label is a string or a positive number, there is no problem: a unicode string is returned, I test it (or convert it to a number, given the circumstances) and everything is fine.

But if the label is a negative number what I get back is a mangled unicode string for a reason I cannot understand.

Let's take this example code:

```
import pylab as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.plot([-1, 0, 1, 2], range(4))
labels = ax.get_xticklabels()
```

now, if I ask the text content of the second label (the `0`) I obtain a normal unicode string:

```
labels[1].get_text()
# u'0.0'
```

but the unicode of the first one (the `-1`) is a strange thing

```
labels[1].get_text()
# u'\u22121'
```

This is printed correctly in the terminal, but in this case I need to confront it with a numerical value, and every conversion fail, both with `int` and `float`.

I tried to convert it to an UTF-8 string with

```
text = labels[1].get_text()
text.encode('utf8')
# '\xe2\x88\x921'
```

but again it is something that is correctly printed and raise an error when converted. I also looked to the `unicodedata` module, but looks like it can only convert single character, so in this case is useless. I've tried also to normalize the string with `unicodedata.normalize` and any possible format, but again no success.

I moved to the pipy module `unidecode` (as suggested in [Python and character normalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162603/python-and-character-normalization)), again without any success

```
from unidecode import unidecode
unidecode(text)
# '[?]1'
```

I have tried also to avoid font issues using the solution in [Non-ASCII characters in Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960463/non-ascii-characters-in-matplotlib), but with the same result (I'm not sure if it should even have something to do, being that a problem of visualization...). the question [Accented characters in Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406700/accented-characters-in-matplotlib) has a similar problem, as it is concerned about the visualization and not the value in itself

I'm starting to feel a little lost...I know that python 2.7 has some unicode "difficulty", but normally I can avoid them in a way or the other.

I know that the issue is the minus sign, as I can avoid the problem using a brute replacement of the culprit:

```
text.replace(u'\u2212', '-')
# u'-1'
```

But this is more and hack than a solution, and I'm almost certain that it's not stable across different systems, so I would like something closer to a *solution*.

I'm working with

- python 2.7.3
- matplotlib 1.2.0
- pylab 1.7.0
- IPython 0.13.1

on Kubuntu 12.10.

Thank you very much for your help!

#### EDIT:

Corrected the order of the plot, as I got the x and y inverted, sorry

#### EDIT2:

a similar info is present at this link:http://www.coniferproductions.com/2012/12/17/unicode-character-dump-in-python/

in the end it shows how in some books the minus sign used is a more estetically pleasant one but not recognized by the python interpreter as a valid character.

#### EDIT3:

Riddle solved. the character that matplotlib return is the "MINUS SIGN", i.e. the correct typografical sign for the minus. The one the keybord create is in fact "HYPHEN-MINUS", that is commonly used but not typografically correct. see on wikipedia for an explanation http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen-minus.

So, the simple replace I used is in fact the correct practical thing to do, but "ethically" is a bug in python (2.7 and 3.x alike) that do not recognize the correct symbol for the minus sign.

see the bug tracking in http://bugs.python.org/issue6632

#### EDIT4:

to disable this behavior there is a simple solution on matplotlib, just modify the rcparams, either in the .matplotlibrc or programmatically.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['axes.unicode_minus']=False
```

Comment: Your last edit solved my problem of minus signs not rendering, thanks

Comment: I suggest you turn your EDIT4 into an answer so that people searching for it can find it more easily!

Comment: I only had this problem when saving as a `pdf` on the `agg` backend using the `Arial` font family. The `png` turned out fine. Any ideas why? Was the `pdf` also the culprit for you? (But your EDIT4 worked for me, thanks!)

Comment: Your last edit should actually be an answer itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All valid unicode characters have names. We can inspect the name for recognized numerical words (`DIGIT.keys()`) and on that basis substitute "normal" numerical characters (`DIGIT.values()`) for the given unicode label:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import unicodedata as UD

DIGIT = {
    'MINUS': u'-',
    'ZERO': u'0',
    'ONE': u'1',
    'TWO': u'2',
    'THREE': u'3',
    'FOUR': u'4',
    'FIVE': u'5',
    'SIX': u'6',
    'SEVEN': u'7',
    'EIGHT': u'8',
    'NINE': u'9',
    'STOP': u'.'
    }

def guess(unistr):
    return ''.join([value for u in unistr
                    for key,value in DIGIT.iteritems()
                    if key in UD.name(u)])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.plot([-1, 0, 1, 2], range(4))
plt.savefig('/tmp/test.png')
labels = ax.get_xticklabels()
for label in labels:
    label = label.get_text()
    print(guess(label))
```

yields

```
-1.0
-0.5
0.0
0.5
1.0
1.5
2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `plt.xticks()` instead of `ax.get_xticklabels()`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.plot([-1, 0, 1, 2], range(4))
plt.savefig('/tmp/test.png')
loc, labels = plt.xticks()
print(type(loc))
# <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
print(loc)
# [-1.  -0.5  0.   0.5  1.   1.5  2. ]
```

Comment: +1 But they might be actually trying to check the text labels are valid

Comment: I'm sorry, but this doesn't help, as the thing that I need to check, the text labels, are the same as in the other case, with the same exact problem of a strange unicode minus sign.

Comment: @EnricoGiampieri: What are the valid characters that you want the labels translated to? For example, is `list('01234567890.-')` the complete list?

Comment: Yes, in this case that is the expected list.