# Plots with unicode character

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, unicode, python-unicode

I need to put greek letters in labels of a matplotlib plot . how can I do it? For instance, unicode Omega is : `u\u03A9`. I use `plt.xlabel('label')`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accented characters in Matplotlib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406700/accented-characters-in-matplotlib)

Comment: what do you get on plot now ? If `plt.xlabel(u'\u03A9')` doesn't work then maybe you need font with this char.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking specifically for greek letter, you can use LaTex in-line math formatting commands (i.e. `'$\Omega$'`) to produce letter that are in the Latex character map.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(np.arange(1000), np.random.rand(1000), 'b.')
plt.xlabel('$\Omega$', size=16)
```

[image]

Here are good resources for finding LaTex symbols.

- PDF list: https://www.rpi.edu/dept/arc/training/latex/LaTeX_symbols.pdf
- Draw your symbol, get a bunch of LaTex characters: http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

Comment: Ok, thanks! It gives me the error `ValueError: invalid \x escape`. Do I need  to include some modules?

Comment: Without seeing more code, I don't what is causing the error.  Did copying the above code not work for you?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not positive about matplotlib, but I would assume that declaring them as unicode strings should work

```
>>> print u'\u03A9' 
Ω
```

Comment: what do you mean by declaring them? i put in plot() `''u\u03A9' '` ,  `u'\u03A9'` `u'\u03A9` but none of them worked :\

Comment: @user129511 I mean putting the `u`in front of the the string like so `u'\u03A9'`.  By prefixing the string with a `u`, one is declaring the type of string as unicode. If we were declaring a byte string it would be `b'some bytes'`