# Accented Latex letters in Matplotlib label

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex, axis-labels

My question is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406700/accented-characters-in-matplotlib).

I want to display for instance `$\tilde{b}$` as ylabel in a Matplotlib plot.

**MWE**

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
matplotlib.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(np.array([0, 1]), np.array([0, 1]))
plt.ylabel('$\tilde{b}$')
plt.show()
```

The result is that it just shows

```
ilde b
```

on the axis. I thought it was related to the fact that b is a consonant, but is does not work either with vowels.

What can I do?

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/tex_demo.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get that result because in the string you want to render as the label, `'$\tilde{b}$'`, Python recognizes `\t` as a special character: [a horizontal tab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_key#Tab_characters).

It is not the only special character. Another prominent example is `\n`, which represents a line break. The complete list of special characters can be found in section ["String and Bytes literals"](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) of the Python Language Reference.

Section ["Strings"](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings)
in the Python Tutorial notes:

> If you don’t want characters prefaced by \ to be interpreted as special characters, you can use raw strings by adding an r before the first quote:

So you get the desired output if instead of

```py
plt.ylabel('$\tilde{b}$')
```

you use

```py
plt.ylabel(r'$\tilde{b}$')
```

For what it's worth, the line `matplotlib.rc('text', usetex=True)` in your code (which requires a LaTeX installation in addition to just Matplotlib) is not necessary to reproduce the behavior.